# Extending UICollectionViewFlowLayout and setting spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am extending `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for my collection view, but i can't set spacing.

My class:

```
public class HorizontalCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    public var itemSize1 = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    private var cellCount = 0
    private var boundsSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

    public override func prepare() {
        cellCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        boundsSize = self.collectionView!.bounds.size
    }
    public override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        let verticalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.height / itemSize1.height))
        let horizontalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.width / itemSize1.width))

        let itemsPerPage = verticalItemsCount * horizontalItemsCount
        let numberOfItems = cellCount
        let numberOfPages = Int(ceil(Double(numberOfItems) / Double(itemsPerPage)))

        var size = boundsSize
        size.width = CGFloat(numberOfPages) * boundsSize.width
        return size
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var allAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if cellCount > 0 {
        for i in 0...(cellCount-1) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
            let attr = self.computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath: indexPath)
            allAttributes.append(attr)
        }
        }
        return allAttributes
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    public override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    private func computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath:IndexPath)
        -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
            let row = indexPath.row
            let bounds = self.collectionView!.bounds

            let verticalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.height / itemSize1.height))
            let horizontalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.width / itemSize1.width))
            let itemsPerPage = verticalItemsCount * horizontalItemsCount

            let columnPosition = row % horizontalItemsCount
            let rowPosition = (row/horizontalItemsCount)%verticalItemsCount
            let itemPage = Int(floor(Double(row)/Double(itemsPerPage)))

            let attr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

            var frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0)
            frame.origin.x = CGFloat(itemPage) * bounds.size.width + CGFloat(columnPosition) * itemSize1.width
            frame.origin.y = CGFloat(rowPosition) * itemSize1.height
            frame.size = itemSize1
            attr.frame = frame

            return attr
    }
}
```

My `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let itemWidth = 100
        let itemHeight = 100
        let horizontalCV = HorizontalCollectionViewLayout();
        horizontalCV.minimumLineSpacing=100   
        horizontalCV.minimumInteritemSpacing=100
        horizontalCV.itemSize1 = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)

        instagramCollection.collectionViewLayout = horizontalCV
        self.instagramCollection.delegate=self
        self.instagramCollection.dataSource=self
}
```

As you can see i am setting it in `viewDidLoad` method with

```
horizontalCV.minimumLineSpacing=100
horizontalCV.minimumInteritemSpacing=100
```

But it is not working always using 0 spacing.

Result:

[image]

**How can i set spacing?**